# How can nutch be configured to crawl only the updated pages in the website

Tags: nutch

For example if my website contains 10 urls in total, in my first crawl I crawl all the urls and when I crawl second time, it should crawl only the urls/pages which has changes and do not crawl other pages.Can nutch use sitemaps to determine the pages which have changed and crawl them.

Comment: see this https://www.pascaldimassimo.com/2010/06/11/how-to-re-crawl-with-nutch/

Comment: I have already seen that it talks about adaptive search but, I want nutch to refer sitemaps and crawl the recent updated pages.